# Partial Screen not Scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a screen where the ListView is populated through the API response but the problem I faced is that the screen is only scrolling vertically when it is scrolled pointing above the ListView but the screen is not scrolling when it is scrolled pointing at any other point on the ListView.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:walk_himalaya/pages/Test/TestPlaceAttr.dart';
    import 'package:walk_himalaya/utils/UserConstants.dart';
    import 'package:walk_himalaya/utils/himayan_walk_constant.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';
    void main() {
    runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: TravelHomePage(),
    ));
    }

    class TravelHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    TravelHomePageState createState() => new TravelHomePageState();
    }

    class TravelHomePageState extends State<TravelHomePage> {
    String access_token = UserConstants.userAccessToken;
    String token_type = UserConstants.bearerType;

    Future<List<dynamic>> getCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(HimalayanWalkConstant.baseURL + "places", headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': '$token_type' + ' $access_token'
    });
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedCategories = json.decode(response.body);
    return decodedCategories['data'];
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Destination Page"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(UserConstants.userDisplayName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Text(
                      "Where do you want to go?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      new NetworkImage(UserConstants.userProfileUrl),
                  radius: 40,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Find destination",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getCategories(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Map<String, String> data =
                          snapshot.data[index].cast<String, String>();
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => _openDestinationPage(context),
                            child: _buildFeaturedItem(
                              image: data['featured_image_url'],
                              title: data['title'],
                              subtitle: data['slug'],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
   }

   Container _buildFeaturedItem({String image, String title, String subtitle}) {
   return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 8.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
    child: Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              child: Image.network(
                image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          Positioned(
            right: 10.0,
            top: 10.0,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text(subtitle, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   );
   }

   _openDestinationPage(BuildContext context) {
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
   DestinationPage()));
   }
```

[image: The screen is scrolling when it is scrolled by pointing on the red surface only.]

to conclude What i am trying to do is to Scroll the whole Screen Vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the optimized code, use this instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:walk_himalaya/pages/Test/TestPlaceAttr.dart';
import 'package:walk_himalaya/utils/UserConstants.dart';
import 'package:walk_himalaya/utils/himayan_walk_constant.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: TravelHomePage(),
  ));
}

class TravelHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  TravelHomePageState createState() => new TravelHomePageState();
}

class TravelHomePageState extends State<TravelHomePage> {
  String access_token = UserConstants.userAccessToken;
  String token_type = UserConstants.bearerType;

  Future<List<dynamic>> getCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(HimalayanWalkConstant.baseURL + "places", headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': '$token_type' + ' $access_token'
    });
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedCategories = json.decode(response.body);
    return decodedCategories['data'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Destination Page"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(UserConstants.userDisplayName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Text(
                      "Where do you want to go?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      new NetworkImage(UserConstants.userProfileUrl),
                  radius: 40,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Find destination",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
            child: Material(
              child: buildListItems(getCategories()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Card _buildFeaturedItem({String image, String title, String subtitle}) {
  return Card(
    child: Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              child: new Image(
                image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          Positioned(
            right: 10.0,
            top: 10.0,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text(subtitle, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

SizedBox buildListItems(Future<List> categories) {
  final ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();
  return SizedBox(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: categories,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Map<String, String> data =
                  snapshot.data[index].cast<String, String>();
              return new Container(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _openDestinationPage(context),
                  child: _buildFeaturedItem(
                    image: data['featured_image_url'],
                    title: data['title'],
                    subtitle: data['slug'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}

_openDestinationPage(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DestinationPage()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a listview within a listview, scrolling is going to be wonky. You could set the inner item's `shrinkWrap` to true which will make it determine its height based on all of the items, but that could cause performance issues in a list with a lot of items. I'd suggest using a CustomScrollView as the overall scrolling pane, with a RenderSliverToBoxAdapter for the top thing and then a SliverList for the pictures. I'm not sure that you can do it with the futurebuilder within the sliverlist though - you might have to move that outside of the CustomScrollView.